# Xcode Errors for new App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I recently hired a guy to program an app for me and in the final delivered app it has 132 errors when it compiles. In truth they are more warnings than errors, but not sure how worried I should be about it.

The types of things listed are:

```
Semantic Issue
/TestViewController.m:220:23: Assigning to 'id<UIWebViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'TestViewController *const __strong'

/TestViewController.m:186:27: 'UITextAlignmentCenter' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0

/TestViewController.m:176:13: Unused variable 'frameY'

/MBProgressHUD.m:429:24: 'UITextAlignmentCenter' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0
```

The app is running just fine, and overall I am very impressed with the developer, I just need to know if this is a problem in waiting, or if I can ignore them?

We had an Adobe Air app recently we spent an initial $30K on, then another $30K to change frameworks, then with the new iOS errors our app broke for about 6 months while trying to find someone to fix it. Just a little gun shy about launching a brand new app with 132 errors :)

Comment: They are "only" warnings, but the fact that the developer hasn't bothered to fix them would worry me about the quality of their work. You should at least review all 132 errors in case any of them are potentially serious.

Comment: I wouldn't pay for or trust code that didn't compile clean. If the code doesn't even compile without warnings, who knows what other hidden problems there are.

Comment: You don't say how big this project is.  That might not be too bad (though certainly could be better) for a 50 KLOC project, but is way too much for a 5 KLOC project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having 132 warnings for a final product is never a great sign. That said, the four examples you listed are probably not showstoppers – they're more indicative of lazy programmer behavior. And while these particular warnings aren't going to cause issues, if I were you, I'd be rather worried that the developer saw fit to deliver a "finished" product with warnings, much less 132 of them.

Comment: The 1st warning could actually be critical. Since the class wan't properly marked as conforming to the protocol, it's possible that some required protocol methods are missing but the compiler can't make the proper checks. The 3rd warning could be benign or it could mean there is a terrible bug since the wrong variable was referenced by mistake.

Comment: @rmaddy well, I checked: `UIWebViewDelegate`'s methods are all optional. And for the 3rd one, yes, it could theoretically be awful. It's far more likely it's just vestigial, though.

Comment: The `UIWebViewDelegate` may have all optional but that's just one of 132. Who knows what the others are. Regardless, we all agree it's bad to have so many issues.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the good news:

-the app will probably run fine with the warnings

-it would take about 10 mins to fix all the warnings

Here's the bad news:

-I would seriously question the quality of the product you received from any developer that would release it to you with all these warnings.

-It will probably break when future versions of iOS come out and the deprecated methods disappear (and iOS 8 is just around the corner).

In general, I find it hard to imagine how a developer could work on a product that showed all those warnings every time they compiled and ignored them. The only conclusion I can reach is that the developer was copying and pasting old code samples and tutorials they found on the Internet into your app and when the warnings appeared (because the sample code was old) they ignored them because they didn't know how to fix them or understand the code they were using. The one conclusion you can make for sure is that your developer is a beginner and the app will not be pretty under the hood. The question you have to answer is whether you care or not.